# No query params when rendering routed component in unit test

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I am attempting to test a specific route within my React component that relies on the window having visible search parameters. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    if (window.location.search) {
        return <h1 data-testid="query">Has search params</h1>
    }

    return <h1 data-testid="no-query">No search params</h1>
}
```

My test for such an occurance is as such:

```
it('should go down query route', () => {
    const initialState = configState(); // Set up Redux store

    const path = '/my-comp';
    const search = '?some=search';

    const history = createMemoryHistory({
        initialEntries: [{
           pathname: path, 
           search: search
        }]
    });
    history.push(redirectFrom);

    const mockStore = configureStore();
    
    const {queryByTestId} = render (
        <Provider store={mockStore(state)}>
           <Router history={history}>
              <MyComponent />
           </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
    
    expect(queryByTestId('query')).not.toBeNull();
    expect(queryByTestId('query').textContent).toBe('Has search params');

    expect(queryByTestId('no-query')).toBeNull();
});
```

I found that the tests weren't passing, so I added a `console.log(window.location)` at the start of my component to see the `path`, `search` etc that the component was being rendered with and I found that all of the expected properties were missing:

```
{ 
    href: 'http://localhost/',
    origin: 'http://localhost',
    host: 'localhost',
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: '',
    pathname: '/',
    search: '',
    hash: '' 
}
```

---

**A bit of background info:**

- The App is built with Redux
- This component is rendered as part of a `<Router>` within an App as you might expect:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider>
           <ConnectedRouter>
              <Route path="my-comp" component={MyComponent} />
              // More routes here
           </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you try getting them via the router, e.g. using the hooks, rather than directly from the window object? Or conversely setting the dummy values on the global window object in the test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah I have not... I may have a look at the dummy window first, and then look at the hook - I think I have only seen it mentioned yesterday so worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for suggesting I look into the router hooks.

I ended up using the `useLocation` hook (I thought the `useParam` would work, but this would not access query params unfortunately).

This was essentially a direct swap for what I was doing.

**Before**

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    if (window.location.search) {
        return <h1 data-testid="query">Has search params</h1>
    }
```

**After**

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    if (location.search) {
        return <h1 data-testid="query">Has search params</h1>
    }
```

Doing this and keeping the `console.log` in to show what the component is being rendering showed exactly what I had specified with the mock history I had passed in during the test:

```
const history = createMemoryHistory({
        initialEntries: [{
           pathname: path, 
           search: search
        }]
    });
```